# swapping the any 2 digits of an number based on its position

Tags: c

```
What would be the logic of swapping any two digits of any number based on its position?
```

For example in 57896, depending on the position of any two digit It has to be swapped.
    Like 1st position with 3rd or 2nd with fifth and then print the swapped no..

Comment: You should share what you have tried or done before, people here won't do your homework!

Comment: Actually I am confused about How to swap digits of number.I am able to swap two letters of string but unable to think the logic of above concern..

Comment: I would recommend using some math

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this numerically, which will be much faster than "going in and out of a string". I'll work through swapping the 2 and 5 in the number 12345 and, hopefully, you can generalise the approach. Denote the difference between the original number and the number with the digits swapped as `d`.

1. Compute the difference between the two digits that are to be swapped. In your case that's 5 - 2 = 3. Note the sign convention carefully.
2. Since 2 is in the 1000's position, and the 5 in the units position, the difference `d` will be 3 * 1000 - 3 * 1 = 2997. Note that the sign of the second term will be the opposite of the first term.
3. Add that to the original number to obtain your result.

As another example, consider swapping 2 and 3 from 12345. The difference is 1, 2 is in the 1000's position and 3 in the 100's position. Therefore the difference is 1 * 1000 - 1 * 100 = 900. And you add that to the original number.